# How to make form disabled in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. So, I have a form and buttons that I have created. But, for some reason, my form is not disabled. All I want to do is when the user comes to the page, I want the form to be disabled. Thank you.

> Here is my code.

```
  <a class="back" href="#/user">Back</a>

  <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
    Edit
  </button>

  <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>



  <div class="people-view">

    <h2 class="name">{{audience.firstName}}</h2>

    <h2 class="name">{{audience.lastName}}</h2>

    <span class="title">{{audience.email}}</span>

    <span class="date">{{audience.website}} </span>

  </div>

  <div class="list-view">

    <form>

      <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <b>First Name:</b>

        <input type="text" ng-model="audience.firstName">
        <br>

        <b>Last Name:</b>

        <input type="text" ng-model="audience.lastName">
        <br>

        <b>Email:</b>

        <input type="email" ng-model="audience.email">

      </fieldset>

    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

> JS

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


   $scope.inactive = true;

   }
```

Comment: wether form you want to disable or elements in the form

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  Click here to disable all the form fields:<input type="checkbox" ng-model="all"><br>
  <br>
  <a class="back" href="#/user">Back</a>
  <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive"> Edit </button>
  <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">Save</button>

  <div class="people-view">
    <h2 class="name"> {{audience.firstName}}</h2>
    <h2 class="name">{{audience.lastName}}</h2>
    <span class="title">{{audience.email}}</span>
    <span class="date">{{audience.website}} </span>
  </div>

  <div class="list-view">
    <form>
      <fieldset ng-disabled>
        <legend>Basic Info</legend>
        <b>First Name:</b>
        <input type="text" ng-model="audience.firstName" ng-disabled="all">
        <br>
        <b>Last Name:</b>
        <input type="text" ng-model="audience.lastName" ng-disabled="all">
        <br>
        <b>Email:</b>
        <input type="email" ng-model="audience.email" ng-disabled="all">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please take a look at this JSFiddle!
https://jsfiddle.net/rickydam/fstkcs26/

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please mark it as correct to help others who might also come across the same problem as you! :)

Comment: thank you. But I fixed it.  I just added a <div class="MainCtrl"> and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your fields in fieldset and use ngDisabled directive like this:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="inactive"> ... input fields ...</fieldset>
```

It will automatically disable all inputs inside the fieldset.

Then in controller set $scope.inactiveto true.

Comment: @BillyJr. just change the `isSaving` to `inactive`

Comment: when user click on edit button then set inactive to false.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the native html attribute?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="audience.firstName" disabled>
```

Or you can use the `ng-disabled` directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="audience.firstName" ng-disabled="inactive">
```

Comment: I don't like that way. Can you check why the form is enabled, but I want the form to be disabled

Comment: How about `ng-disabled` directive?